# request.urlretrieve in multiprocessing Python gets stuck

Tags: python, multiprocessing, urllib, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to download images from a list of URLs using Python. To make the process faster, I used the multiprocessing library.

The problem I am facing is that the script often hangs/freezes on its own, and I don't know why.

Here is the code that I am using

```
...
import multiprocessing as mp

def getImages(val):

    #Dowload images
    try:
        url= # preprocess the url from the input val
        local= #Filename Generation From Global Varables And Rand Stuffs...
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,local)
        print("DONE - " + url)
        return 1
    except Exception as e:
        print("CAN'T DOWNLOAD - " + url )
        return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':

    files = "urls.txt"
    lst = list(open(files))
    lst = [l.replace("\n", "") for l in lst]

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
    res = pool.map(getImages, lst)

    print ("tempw")
```

It often gets stuck halfway through the list (it prints DONE, or CAN't DOWNLOAD to half of the list it has processed but I don't know what is happening on the rest of them). Has anyone faced this problem? I have searched for similar problems (e.g. this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943923/requests-get-hangs-when-called-in-a-multiprocessing-pool)) but found no answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found an answer.

A possible culprit was the script was stuck in connecting/downloading from the URL. So what I added was a **socket timeout** to limit the time to connect and download the image.

And now, the issue no longer bothers me.

Here is my complete code

```
...
import multiprocessing as mp

import socket

# Set the default timeout in seconds
timeout = 20
socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)

def getImages(val):

    #Dowload images
    try:
        url= # preprocess the url from the input val
        local= #Filename Generation From Global Varables And Rand Stuffs...
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,local)
        print("DONE - " + url)
        return 1
    except Exception as e:
        print("CAN'T DOWNLOAD - " + url )
        return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':

    files = "urls.txt"
    lst = list(open(files))
    lst = [l.replace("\n", "") for l in lst]

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=4)
    res = pool.map(getImages, lst)

    print ("tempw")
```

Hope this solution helps others who are facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're facing a GIL issue : The python Global Interpreter Lock basically forbid python to do more than one task at the same time.
The `Multiprocessing` module is really launching separate instances of python to get the work done in parallel.

But in your case, urllib is called in all these instances : each of them is trying to lock the IO process : the one who succeed (e.g. come first) get you the result, while the others (trying to lock an already locked process) fail.

This is a very simplified explanation, but here are some additionnal ressources :

You can find another way to parallelize requests here : [Multiprocessing useless with urllib2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905800/multiprocessing-useless-with-urllib2)

And more info about the GIL here : [What is a global interpreter lock (GIL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-a-global-interpreter-lock-gil)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not sure GIL was the culprit, but it is useful to learn that GIL was one of the possible cases.